# How am I suddenly using property driver?

Tags: drivers, 15.04

[image]

I just fresh installed ubuntu 15.04. I accidentally opened additional divers tab to find out that I'm using Intel property driver. In previous releases it always showed that no property driver is in use, and there are no property drivers available. How am I suddenly using one? I do feel that my computer is maybe a little bit faster though. I'm afraid that i broke something if I disable it. Can someone please explain this weird thing and advice me weather I should disable it or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option comes with ubuntu 15.04. Its nothing so serious and yes you can disable it without breaking anything but my advice is to keep it enabled as it makes your pc a bit faster.